# django: How to make copy of one of the objects in the db

Tags: sql, django

I wonder if there is a way to make a copy of one db item?

e.g. I have a model

```
class Category(models.Model):
    slug = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
```

So if I added one item, how can i clone it 100 times for testing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the model has an autoincrement PK (the default) then you can create or retrieve the object once, then wipe the PK before saving it:

```
row = SomeModel(...)
for i in xrange(100:
  row.pk = None
  row.save()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
# Create a bunch of new objects
for i in xrange(0,100):
    new_cat = Category(slug='a-slug', name="My Name")
    new_cat.save()
```

If you're just looking to populate your database for testing purposes, you may want to look at using [fixtures](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/#fixture-loading) instead.

Comment: But to create fixture you need objects in db (to dump)....Correct? 

What if my category model has 10 fields?

Comment: Why does the number of fields matter?

Comment: So I do add them to the constructor?